# warning CS0618: 'ResourceManager.ResourceSets' is obsolete: 'call InternalGetResourceSet instead'

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, .net-4.6.1

I see this warning in the DevOps build log file.

I don't get a warning when I build on my own computer.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe /noconfig
>   /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:TRACE
>   /highentropyva+ /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.1\mscorlib.dll"
>   /reference:d:\a\1\s\Common\bin\Release\SBD.Common.dll
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Core.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Data.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Drawing.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.ServiceModel.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Windows.Forms.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Xml.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Xml.Linq.dll"
>   /debug:pdbonly /filealign:512 /optimize+
>   /out:obj\Release\SBD.Common.WinForms.dll /ruleset:"C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Team Tools\Static
>   Analysis Tools\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset"
>   /subsystemversion:6.00
>   /resource:obj\Release\SBD.Common.WinForms.AboutDialogBase.resources
>   /resource:obj\Release\SBD.Common.WinForms.DatabaseConnectDialog.resources
>   /resource:AboutIcon.ico,SBD.Common.WinForms.AboutIcon.ico
>   /resource:AboutTemplate.rtf,SBD.Common.WinForms.AboutTemplate.rtf
>   /target:library /utf8output AboutDialogBase.cs
>   AboutDialogBase.Designer.cs AuthenticateResult.cs CredentialsDialog.cs
>   CREDUI.cs DatabaseConnectDialog.cs DatabaseConnectDialog.Designer.cs
>   FileBasedResourceManager.cs FileBasedResourceSet.cs FormUtils.cs
>   MessagePop.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs
>   "C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
>         Using shared compilation with compiler from directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn
>       ##[warning]Common.WinForms\FileBasedResourceManager.cs(72,62): Warning CS0618: 'ResourceManager.ResourceSets' is obsolete: 'call
>   InternalGetResourceSet instead'

The project has the following
[image: files]

Comment: Do you use Hosted agent ot Private agent?

Comment: I am using the VS2017 hosted agent

Comment: What is your target framework of your project?

Comment: I experienced the problem using 4.6.1 and then switched to 4.5.2 but that did not help.

Comment: @KirstenGreed, AFAIK, ResourceSets is obsolete in `.net 4.0`, so switch to 4.5.2 will not resolve this warning. Clear this  warning, you may need to switch 3.5 and below. Why not try to the suggestion using `call InternalGetResourceSet`? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/af1f4b4d-2b83-4b6a-be03-6d3de4221f4f/inherit-from-resourcemanager-net-40?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: That is the answer, care to write it up? Strange that I wasn't seeing warnings when I built on my local machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> warning CS0618: 'ResourceManager.ResourceSets' is obsolete: 'call InternalGetResourceSet instead'

AFAIK, `ResourceSets` was obsoleted in `.net 4.0`, so switch to 4.5.2 will not resolve this warning. Clear this warning, you may need to switch `.net 3.5` and below.

Besides, you can try the suggestion in the log, using `call InternalGetResourceSet` instead. Check [the thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/af1f4b4d-2b83-4b6a-be03-6d3de4221f4f/inherit-from-resourcemanager-net-40?forum=csharpgeneral) for some more details.

Hope this helps.